# Python TKInter close window

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a homepage that when you click a button, it opens another window. When I close the index and open up the first window, everything works out fine, but when I try to open up the index from the first window, it gives me an error:

```
return_but["command"] = viewwindestroy
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'destroy'
```

Here is my code:

```
return_but = Button(app,text = "Return to Home")
return_but["command"] = viewwin.destroy()
```

The function:

```
def viewwindestroy(): 
    viewwin.destroy()
```

Comment: 1. Is there a function `viewwin` anywhere in your code? 2. Have you tried assigning a command of `viewwin.destroy` instead of `viewwin.destroy()` (no parentheses at the end)?

Comment: Thanks. Works like a gem!